# How can you logout from scifi website?

Tags: discussion

this website scifi.stackexchange has no visible "button" to click logout. on other websites we can click the name of profile and choose logout but not this site so how can we logout?

Comment: The "StackExchange" logo in the upper-left is a dropdown, it's under there

Comment: @Izkata And in a short time (already for me on SFF), that logo will no longer be a dropdown and you'll have to find a different logo on the top right instead. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300829/278659

Comment: When in doubt, delete your cookies